# Throwing darts in a rocket ship

Tags: general-relativity, acceleration, observers, rocket-science, geodesics

Far from major gravitational sources...

A man is standing throwing darts at a dartboard in a rocket ship. The thrust is upwards so he feels almost like he would on Earth but the G-force is slightly stronger. If he throws the dart straight at the bulls-eye without compensating for the thrust it will of course land below the bulls-eye. It will seem to travel in an arc.

How will this appear to an external, inertial observer (if there was a window)?

They will see the dart traveling in a straight line obviously and the ship moving upwards so the dart can’t meet the target.

The arc the astronaut sees is an optical illusion created by the smooth continuous motions of dart and ship.

Because the astronaut is moving with the ship he sees the dart’s motion (and its position relative to the ship).

Because the observer is not moving they see the dart’s motion, the ship’s motion (and their positions relative to each other).

It seems like the inertial observer has more information.

Can this be so?

Comment: Does the astranout sees the outside observer also?

Comment: It is not an illusion, it is the actual trajectory in that system of reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems like the inertial observer has more information.

Not really. If the astronaut sees the external observer accelerating away from them then they have the same information. And from either point of view  there are two different possible explanations for the dart’s behaviour:

1. The astronaut is indeed in an accelerating spaceship.
2. The astronaut is playing darts on top of the Eiffel Tower and the external observer has just fallen off.

Comment: Lol! He should be able to keep a (brief) eye on the observer unless the Eiffel Tower is going at light speed.

Comment: I’m accepting this answer. Not because it’s the only one but because Balrogs add considerable mass to falling observers. Thanks.